# FirebaseMessagingService onReceivedMessage(RemteMessage rm) doesnot call while application service is killed mode in oreo version

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo

In my Android application, I want to start my service through Push Notification while my application service is killed. This is done for below versions(up-to Nougat-7.1.1). But the Problem is: in Oreo version, it's not working.

I followed below link to create Channel ID for oreo version:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

When the application is initially launched(After launching the app, I closed my application and stopSelf() Service). Again I try to send Push Notification from third-party server to device, the notification doesn't received( **onMessageReceive()** method doesn't called). In this case, third party server sent push notification successfully.

How to fix this issue?  Thanks in Advance!

My build.gradle is:

```
         android {

              compileSdkVersion 27                              
              buildToolsVersion '26.0.2' 

               defaultConfig {     

                 minSdkVersion 18                             
                 targetSdkVersion 27                           
                 multiDexEnabled true                           
                 versionCode 1                                      
                 versionName "1.0.9"                               

                 ndk {                                              
                      abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"          
                  }                                                   
              }
          }
```

Comment: Do you get notification in notification tray when app is closed ?

Comment: in Oreo version i didn't get notification in notification tray

Comment: in oreo version my app service running either foreground or background i received pushnotification.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are getting proper `refreshedToken` in `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and also check the `API KEY`.

```
@Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> > I want to start my service through push notification while my application service is in killing mode.

In Oreo you cannot start a service when your app is in background until its a foreground service.You can only start a foreground services when you app is close or killed else it will throw exception to normal services.The normal service will only work when you app is in foreground state

For Sending notification try sending notification through Firebase console and check weather you receiving notification or not

Comment: same problem occur while trying to running lollipop 5.0.1 and vivo 4.4.2 versions,these devices not receiving push notification,how to solve this  issue? @Burhanuddin Rashid

Comment: Did you try sending notification from firebase console ?

Comment: yes i am trying firebase console and also third party application server,but i didnt get notification where application not running background,

Answer (score 0):

> onMessageReceived() method doesn't called

If the server is sending notification payload, `onMessageReceived()` does not get called when the app is in background or killed.

In order to call `onMessageReceived()` always, you server should always send data payloads and remove notification payload completely.

When you are using notification payload - *Firebase will create notification by itself* by parsing notification payload and data will be passed via intent to target activity, when the notification is clicked.

*Previously*, there was a methhod `handleIntent(Intent intent)` in version `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1` but, later on they have removed it and made them to handle entirely by firebase itself.

> I want to start my service through Push Notification while my
>   application service is killed.

You can't. Refer this [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) for more. You have to schedule `job` to perform action in background.

About the notification payload..

It could look like this -

```
{
  "data":{
    "id": 1,
    "key": value
    "key_1": value1
  },
  "to": "target --fhiT7evmZk8:APA91bFJq7Tkly4BtLRXdYvqHno2vHCRkzpJT8QZy0TlIGs......"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android Nougat and Android Oreo, the service doesn't work when the App is killed or running in the background, so just follow the JSON response along with the high priority:

```json
{
    "to": "[add your token]",
    "notification": {
        "body": "Cool offers. Get them before expiring!",
        "title": "Flat 80% discount",
        "icon": "appicon"
    },
    "data" : {
        "name" : "LG LED TV S15",
        "product_id" : "123",
        "final_price" : "2500"
    },
    "priority":"high"
}
```

After that, you can access the JSON from the initial activity by using:

```java
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```